# How can I programmatically access Chrome's Console to do something with 404 responses?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping

My ultimate goal is to provide a working copy of an existing website.

I have used `httrack` which is pretty good, however it's not smart enough to detect deeply nested dependent resources, eg resources that are dynamic and come from js/flash, etc.

I want to basically write a script that looks for all 404 responses in the `Console` tab in Chrome and with the URI, download the files from an external website locally.

For instance, let's say I get this:

404  http://site.localhost/media/images/blah.png
404  http://site.localhost/media/xml/file.xml

I would want my script to loop through all 404s, and detect if the HOST is 'site.localhost', then run a bash command that WGETs the resource from http://actualsite.com/media/images/blah.png.

If anyone can provide insight into how I can programmatically access this portion of the Console, and how I can run bash commands with that then I'm set.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way of dumping Console content just with regular javascript on a page (and would be very surprised if there is one).

You can write an extension that monitors all resources on a page and logs if it is 404. Downloading them using javascript is out of question of course.

To log bad requests you would need to use an [experimental API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.html), something like this:

**background.html:**

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    if(details.statusCode == 404) {
        console.log("Broken resource:", details.url);
    }
}, null, ["statusLine", "responseHeaders"]);
```